# Python add to url

Tags: python, url, urlparse

I have a URL as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/boards/results/current:entry1,current:entry2/modular/table/alltables/alltables/alltables/2011-01-01
```

I need to insert a node 'us' in this case, as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/boards/results/us/current:entry1,current:entry2/modular/table/alltables/alltables/alltables/2011-01-01
```

Using Python's urlparse library, I can get to the path as follows:

```
path = urlparse(url).path
```

... and then using a complicated and ugly routine involving splitting the path based on slashes and inserting the new node and then reconstructing the URL

```
>>> path = urlparse(url).path
>>> path.split('/')
['', 'boards', 'results', 'current:entry1,current:entry2', 'modular', 'table', 'alltables', 'alltables', 'alltables', '2011-01-01']
>>> ps = path.split('/')
>>> ps.insert(4, 'us')
>>> '/'.join(ps)
'/boards/results/current:entry1,current:entry2/us/modular/table/alltables/alltables/alltables/2011-01-01'
>>>
```

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way to accomplish this using default libraries?

EDIT:
The 'results' in the URL is not fixed - it can be 'results' or 'products' or 'prices' and so on. However, it will always be right after 'boards'.

Comment: `url.replace('results/', 'results/us/')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "http://www.example.com/boards/results/current:entry1,current:entry2/modular/table/alltables/alltables/alltables/2011-01-01"
replace_start_word = 'results'
replace_word_length = len(replace_start_word)
replace_index = path.find(replace_start_word)
new_url = '%s/us%s' % (path[:replace_index + replace_word_length], path[replace_index + replace_word_length:])
```